# OCaml rec function for a card game

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, ocaml

I am new in fuctional programming and need to make an easy card game but have trouble with rec funtion.

Suppose I have a list with 5 players. Now I print a menu for each player in the round with the player current hand,then the player drops a card and draws a new one.

I need to run until the deck is out of cards.

This is my code:

```
let rec round deck players =
  match deck with
    | [] -> ()
    | h::t -> (match players with
                  | x::xs -> print_mazo deck;
                    print_play x;
                    let i = read_int () in
                    let (newhand, carta) = drop x.mano i in
                    let (newdeck, newhand2) = draw deck newhand 1 in
                    print_ronda x carta;
                    round newdeck xs
                  | [] -> round newdeck players 
            )
```

I got this error:

```
Error: Unbound value newdeck
```

Comment: looks like the problem is in the line with `read_int`: it should be `read_int ()`

Comment: (1) It would be nice to have a minimized full example that actually compiles. (2) And at least you should have marked the line where the error occurs.

Comment: You can't keep changing your question. It makes the old answers nonsensical.

Comment: I agree with @JeffreyScofield, I didn't understand his answer until I looked at what you edited :-D

Comment: Sorry first time in Stakoverflow, now i know how it works. Thanks all for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, your code is strange. Let me explain why to you :

```
let rec round deck players =
match deck with
  | [] -> ()
  | h::t -> (match players with
              | x::xs -> (* Some code *)
                let (newdeck, newhand2) = draw deck newhand 1 in
                round newdeck xs (* good recursive call *)
              | [] -> round newdeck players (* bad recursive call *)
        )
```

Why is it a `bad recursive call` ? Because you declared `newdeck` in the first branch of your pattern matching but not in the second one. So, when you write `| [] -> round newdeck players` where does that `newdeck` comes from ?

It's like writing

```
let f x = let a = 3 in x + a
let y = a
```

Do you agree with the fact that this `a` was local to `f` ? If you agree, it's the same with your `newdeck` being local to the first branch of the pattern matching.

Comment: Oh I see, i need a way to can use my modified deck in the final patern matching

Comment: Actually, if you look at your code with attention, if the list of players is empty, your `newdeck` is equal to the parameter `deck` since the recursive call to `round` is always done on `newdeck`.

Answer (score 1):

I think your immediate problem is that you have:

```
let i = read_int
```

but you need

```
let i = read_int ()
```

`read_int` by itself is a function, which is a fairly ordinary value in OCaml (and any FP language). So it's not an error to bind `i` to this value. However, the compiler notices that the value doesn't have the right type, namely `int`. You want to actually *call* the function; i.e., you need to apply it to an input value. In the case of `read_int` it always takes the same input value, `()`.

Skimming through the rest of your code, I don't see any use of the value `t`. I suspect there's some more work to do to go through the list of players.